# How to change button text depending on clicked button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a simple step by step guide with Vue.js. Now, I have a simple copy to clipboard button which copies peace of text.
Now, I want to create a feedback for the user when they click on the copy button. 
My approach was to do it like this:

```
<button class="copyButton" @click="copiedNotice();">{{btnText}}</button>
```

```
data() {
        return {
            btnText: 'Copy content'
        }
    },
```

```
     copiedNotice: function() {
          this.btnText = 'Copied';
      }
```

This method simply changes the text of the button, but there is one issue. I have 3 of these buttons on one page, and when I click on one, by changing data, it changes all of them instead of one. 
Can someone help?

Comment: Don't use btnText for all 3 buttons if they need to be able to have different values. Or just don't update the button itself. Create one overlay or message output thingy you can change the text for and use that. Then you don't have to change the btnText back to the original state either ( just hide the message thingy ), making everything more simple.

Comment: Why don't you just put an ID on each buttons and refer to the ID so only the button with that ID changes text? or use `btnText1`, `btnText2`, `btnText3`